# LLVM 3.0 bug of LTO in xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, llvm

I tried LTO in xocde 4.2, llvm3.0, I got this error
ld: internal error: atom not found in symbolIndex(___divsi3) for architecture armv7

Is that the llvm bug? or something I need fix?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in LLVM 3.0, I recommend filing a report through bugreport.apple.com.